# ng-repeat display html in particular order

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I got the json message:

And I am trying to load the json message into html in particular order.

You will find the **position** value in json message, the first element in the array: 0 means the order.

Sometimes, the json message is out of order, not like the example.

Is there any way to output the json message in html in order: 0,1,2,3.

The HTML part is:

```
<div class="container">
            <div ng-repeat="question in questions">
                <div class="row">
                    // load the question in increase order
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Json message:

```
[ { "Question" : { "description" : { "default" : "hello" },
        "options" : [ { "value" : {  } } ],
        "title" : { "default" : "hello world" }
      },
    "Selection" : "text",
    "position" : [ 0,
        12,
        0
      ]
  },
  { "Question" : { "description" : { "default" : "hello 2" },
        "options" : [ { "value" : {  } } ],
        "title" : { "default" : "hello 2" }
      },
    "Selection" : "paragraph",
    "position" : [ 1,
        12,
        0
      ]
  },
  { "Question" : { "description" : { "default" : "hello 3" },
        "options" : [ { "value" : { "default" : "1" } },
            { "value" : { "default" : "2" } }
          ],
        "title" : { "default" : "hello 3" }
      },
    "Selection" : "radio",
    "position" : [ 2,
        12,
        0
      ]
  },
  { "Question" : { "description" : { "default" : "hello 4" },
        "options" : [ { "value" : { "default" : "check11" } },
            { "value" : { "default" : "check22" } }
          ],
        "title" : { "default" : "hello 4" }
      },
    "Selection" : "checkbox",
    "position" : [ 3,
        12,
        0
      ]
  },
  { "Question" : { "description" : { "default" : "hello 5" },
        "options" : [ { "value" : { "default" : "list1" } },
            { "value" : { "default" : "list2" } }
          ],
        "title" : { "default" : "hello 5" }
      },
    "Selection" : "list",
    "position" : [ 4,
        12,
        0
      ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the first item in the position array to the orderBy filter:

```
ng-repeat="question in questions | orderBy:'position[0]'"
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GruffBunny/6M7mj/)</kbd>

Comment: Hi, many thank! but I found if you change the json order in 5 4 3 2 1, it will print in 5 4 3 2 1, not in 1 2 3 4 5

Answer (score 0):

Try using [orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy):

```
<tr ng-repeat="question in questions | orderBy:<function>">
  ...      
</tr>
```

Comment: Hi I tried ng-repeat="question in questions | orderBy: question.position[0]:reverse", but it still prints in order

Comment: position is an array, will position[0] work? what if I want to in reverse order

Comment: try to write a function to determine the required order